# JSF configuration not available while creating new project in eclipse Photon (EE version)

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I am trying to create a New Dynamic Project in Eclipse. In my configuration tab in the new project window; JSF config is not available as shown in the image:

[image]

Can anyone tell the reason? How can I get it here?

Comment: Afaik, there has never been one available. Better to create it from a maven archetype of eben by hand. It is very little work and a description available in almost any tutorial. Don't rely on the ide for this https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Is there an image you're using as a reference that shows it is supposed to be there? Are the JSF tools installed?

Comment: I have got it resolved; but clicking the modify button and selecting the JSF type from there. It was checked from the modification listings hence was not displaying in the tab. Thanks alot for the time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it resolved; but clicking the modify button and selecting the JSF type from there. It was checked from the modification listings hence was not displaying in the tab. Thanks alot for the time. :)